# How to get the value of two columns and store in ArrayList

Tags: java, database, spring, exception, arraylist

I am using Spring framework and in the following code, I want to get the latitude and longitude from the database and store it in an `ArrayList` and then calculate distance between them.

The problem is that I cant figure out how to get the value of two columns in a variable, when I do this in following way `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Double` exception thrown

Can anybody help me? I read we can use 2D `ArrayList` but how can I use `ArrayList` in the following code

**RiderService.java**

```
@Component
public class RiderService {

     @Autowired RiderLocationRepository riderLocationRepository;

    public float Location(Double lattitude,Double longitude)
    {
        Double lat2=24.927437;
        Double lng2=67.094412;

          ArrayList<Double> allRidersLocation  = new ArrayList<Double>();
          allRidersLocation= riderLocationRepository.findAllRidersLocation();
          Iterator<Double> iterator = allRidersLocation.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(" DB value " +  iterator.next().doubleValue());
            } 
            float distance=distFrom(lattitude, longitude, lat2, lng2);
            System.out.println("Distance : " + (distance/1000));
            return distance;
    }
```

**RiderRepository**

```
public interface RiderLocationRepository extends JpaRepository<RiderLocation, Long>{

    @Query("select r.latitude,r.longitude from RiderLocation r ")
    ArrayList<Double>  findAllRidersLocation();

}
```

Comment: Hi @maria salahuddin have you debugged it , because it looks like you have a simple problem of convertion between objects and primitive types as it says in the explanation, maybe you can spot the difference in your code.

Comment: @burhancerit But when I select only latitude from database it works fine

Comment: @burhancerit It gets problem when I select two columns from database

Comment: thats simple. you want to store 2 values in 1 double. if you query just 1 column, it can directly be mapped to the arraylist. try it with a map. a map can take 2 values at once (key and value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
public float Location(Double lattitude,Double longitude)
    {
        Double lat2=24.927437;
        Double lng2=67.094412;

          List<RiderLocation> allRidersLocation  = riderLocationRepository.findAll();
          for (RiderLocation riderLocation : allRidersLocation) {
            float distance=distFrom(riderLocation.getLattitude(), riderLocation.getLongitude(), lat2, lng2);
            System.out.println("Distance : " + (distance/1000));
            return distance;
    }
    }
```

In default, `findAll()` method avaiable on CrudRepository

```
public interface RiderLocationRepository extends JpaRepository<RiderLocation, Long>{

}
```

Comment: "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.ivl.townsmate.model.RiderLocation"

Comment: I think problem is fixed now

Comment: changed List<Double> to List<RiderLocation>, mistake sorry

Comment: This is a cut and paste of my original answer, it even has the mistake I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Your query return an array of Object like this :

```
@Query("select r.latitude, r.longitude from RiderLocation r")
ArrayList<Object[]> array =  //execute_your_query();
```

to get your results you can use this :

```
for(Object[] obj : array){//<<---------------list of object with two columns
   double d1 = (Double) obj[0];//<<-------col 1
   double d2 = (Double) obj[1];//<<-------col 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the findAll method which JpaRepository gives you by default, then you need something like this:

```
public float Location(Double lattitude,Double longitude)
    {
        Double lat2=24.927437;
        Double lng2=67.094412;

          List<RiderLocation> allRidersLocation  = riderLocationRepository.findAll();
          for (RiderLocation riderLocation : allRidersLocation) {
            // use the riderLocation as required, it's not clear to me what methods this has!!
            System.out.println("Distance : " + (distance/1000));
            return distance;
    }
```

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.ivl.townsmate.model.RiderLocation`

This error occur :/